# Compiling all stylus files from given folder and its sub-folders

Tags: css, stylus

For example compiling this folder structure,

```
x.styl
|--abc/
|--|--a.styl
|--efg/
|--|--b.styl
```

To

```
build/
|--x.css
|--abc/
|--|--a.css
|--efg/
|--|--b.css
```

Using stylus compiler (compiling styl files from a folder and its subfolders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late on this, and I hope that might help others like it help me, but I found a solution using the package [`stylus-chokidar`](https://github.com/dnsorlov/stylus-chokidar).

> stylus-chokidar
>
> Just slightly modified stylus CLI, that builds files list recursively and watches > them with chokidar (if --watch provided).
>
> Recursion are always enabled, glob patterns not supported.

With this you can have the stylus files compiled in-place recursively (each component will store their own CSS/stylus files).

Comment: Glad I did answer it a year ago - ended finding it again - and the funny thing was that I tried to vote up to myself ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

You can use the --out parameter on building and target a whole folder, it will keep your structure, first you can target a file or folder, and after out the folder or filename you want to have your compiled css

`stylus -c ./project/stylus --out ./myfolder/css`

For:

```
|stylus
|--abc/
|--|--a.styl
|--efg/
|--|--b.styl
```

It would result in something like:

```
|css
|--abc/
|--|--a.css
|--efg/
|--|--b.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late on the game, but I believe I have a solution that is not optimal, but workable for your situation.

per your example, keep the same file/folder structure

```
x.styl  
|--abc/  
|--|--a.styl  
|--efg/  
|--|--b.styl
```

but also include a "combination.styl" file in its own separate folder. So now you have:

```
x.styl  
|--abc/  
|--|--a.styl  
|--efg/  
|--|--b.styl  
|--all-stylus/  
|--|--combination.styl
```

inside of combination.styl you should import all of the separate .styl files, so for our example

```
// combination.styl  
@import '../x.styl'  
@import '../abc/a.styl'  
//etc...
```

then you can output one large css file wherever you would like!

the command to run this would simply be:

`stylus ./stylus -out ./css`

I know it doesn't give you the output file/folder structure you were looking for, but I imagine it is helpful to be able to compile all of your stylus into css at one time!